# Como excluir a estrutura e os dados do banco de dados mysql

Tags: mysql

Como realizar uma exclusão completa da estrutura de um banco de dados `mysql`?

Preciso excluir todas a `entidades`, `tabelas`, `procedures`, quero ficar apenas com o nome do banco de dados, sem nenhuma tabela ou dados ou qualquer outra coisa vinculada a esse banco.

Existe um comando que faço tal procedimento?

Comment: `DROP database <nome>` ?

Comment: Vou manter o nome do banco? Vai continuar registrado?

Comment: Tudo será removido! qual o objetivo de manter o nome?

Comment: Preciso manter o nome do banco pois estou fazendo experimentos com uma aplicação chamada GLPI que está tendo erro então minha logística para buscar a solução para um problema é instalar as várias versões do sistema até encontrar uma solução.

Comment: @rray conhece algum comando que faça isso?

Comment: @Sergio, pode me ajudar?

Comment: Usando só o MySQL não da para fazer algo tão automatizado assim, utilizar algum script pode facilitar essa tarefa. Não conheço nenhum comando que efetua DROP em todos os objetos da database sem remover ela, pode ver isso pelas respostas, cada uma tenta resolver a limitação de um jeito.

Comment: Entendo. Vou buscar uma solução. Obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Talvez a forma mais automatizada(que imagino) seja criar uma procedure que gere os `drop` e execute um a um.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode matar o database inteiro e refazer com o mesmo nome:

```
DROP database 'meudatabase';
CREATE database 'meudatabase';
```

Se tiver um scritp para criar todo o database melhor ainda, alguma coisa como:

```
#Criando DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE `meudatabase`;

#Criando a tabela TABELA1
CREATE TABLE `meudatabase`.`TABELA1` (
...
```

Comment: Obrigado, isso estou fazendo, mas quero tentar o que foi perguntado.

Answer (score 0):

Deletar todas tabelas do banco:

```
SELECT concat('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', TABLE_NAME, ';') FROM information_schema.TABLES;
```

Comment: Esse comando não é o que estou pedindo.

Comment: @durtto oque você está pedindo?

Comment: Ora bia, é sério?

Comment: Esse comando faz: deletar todas as tabelas do banco,se não foi isso que quis dizer, especifique melhor sua pergunta. @durtto

Comment: Minha pergunta está especificada Bia. Especifique qual sua dúvida.

Comment: Preciso "limpar" a estrutura e os dados do banco de dados, mas preciso manter ele, não quero dropar o banco, quero dropar a estrutura do banco.

Comment: O comando que ela postou dropa as tabelas amigo! Se a resposta dela não te serve usa a do @Ricardo antes que sua pergunta chegue a 300 votos negativos!

Comment: O comando(`SELECT`) gera os `DROP TABLE` das databases, falta um WHERE para especificar qual, depois de gerado você precisa executar os comandos um a um. Não entendi o downvote.

Comment: Eu não me importo se a minha pergunta recebe downvotes. Eu preciso resolver meu problema. Mas infelizmente ninguém captou o que preciso.

Comment: @rray isso mesmo, eu preciso realizar tudo em uma só operação.

Comment: @durtto, quando tem muito comentário pedindo esclarecimento na pergunta e quando as respostas não atendem é porque ***sua pergunta*** não está clara. Em vez de ficar dando explicações em comentários, prefira editar a pergunta para melhorar o entendimento geral.

Comment: @brasofilo minha pergunta é um ótimo exemplo que demostra que as pessoas andam lendo só a primeira linha. Na segunda e demais linhas eu explano o que quero. E outra coisa, a melhor resposta está nos comentários, que fala que o comando que procuro não existe.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, achei uma resposta no SOEN, da uma olhada. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8912749/2161286, imagino que te ajude.

## drop

`mysql -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -e "drop table $table" DATABASE_NAME; done`

## truncate

`mysql -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -e "truncate table $table" DATABASE_NAME; done`

Comment: Poderia me explicar por favor o que esse comando faz?